# Fock state and Slater determinant

Tags: fermions, anticommutator

Let's have Fock state for fermions:
$$
| \mathbf p_{1} , \mathbf p_{2}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\hat {a}^{+}(\mathbf p_{1})\hat {a}^{+}(\mathbf p_{2})| \rangle , \quad | \mathbf p_{2} , \mathbf p_{1}\rangle = -| \mathbf p_{1} , \mathbf p_{2}\rangle .
$$
How to get the expression for Slater determinant by starting from definition above?

Comment: What do you mean expression for Slater determinant? Aren't $| \mathbf p_{1} , \mathbf p_{2}\rangle$ and $|\rangle$ Slater determinants whritten in the occupation number representation?

Comment: @freude . $| \mathbf p_{1} , \mathbf p_{2}\rangle$ is something like a Slater determinant if I write it in form (like full state) of 
$$
| \mathbf p_{1, 2} \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\hat {a}^{+}(\mathbf p_{1})\hat {a}^{+}(\mathbf p_{2})| \rangle - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\hat {a}^{+}(\mathbf p_{2})\hat {a}^{+}(\mathbf p_{1})| \rangle .
$$
But I read about Slater determinant as about
$$
\begin{vmatrix}\psi_{1}(\mathbf p_{1}) & ... & \psi_{n}(\mathbf p_{1}) \\ \psi_{n}(\mathbf p_{1}) & ... & ...\psi_{n}(\mathbf p_{n}) \end{vmatrix}.
$$
I don't see how to connect there expressions.

Comment: You're in second quantization (occupation number represenation). for slater determinant, you'd have to go to first quantization. I'm sure you know the difference between these?

Comment: @user25701 . But Slater determinant,
$$
\psi (\mathbf x_{1}, ...\mathbf x_{n}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{a_{i}}(-1)^{number of permutations}\psi_{a_{i}}(\mathbf x_{1})...\psi_{a_{n}}(\mathbf x_{n}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(Slater determinant)
$$
is antisymmetric with respect $\mathbf x_{1}, ...\mathbf x_{n}$ as well as with respect to single-particle states $a_{i}$, so it may be identified with n-particle fermionic state $f_{n}(\mathbf p)$.

Comment: I've never seen a slater determinant with creation and annihilation operators in it. There are wavefunctions in it.. "It may be identified" means it's a representation of an n-particle fermionic state in first quantization.

Comment: @JohnTaylor, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}a^+_{p1}a^+_{p2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}a^+_{p2}a^+_{p1}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}a^+_{p1}a^+_{p2}$ so you don't need two terms. Only the first term produce the Slater determinant

Comment: @richard . How exactly it produce the Slater determinant? Can you show this, if you please?

Comment: @user25701 . But $\hat {a}^{+}(\mathbf p )| \rangle$ refers to the wave function of free one-particle state, doesn't it?

Comment: @JohnTaylor, $a^+_{p1}a^+_{p2}$ just creates two particles ie the state $|n_{p1}=1,n_{p2}=1 \rangle $ which by definition is a 2x2 slater determinant.

Comment: But how to write it in a form of Slater determinant? Something like
$$
\begin{vmatrix} \hat {a}^{+}(\mathbf p_{1}) & \hat {a}^{+}(\mathbf p_{2}) \\ \hat {a}^{+}(\mathbf p_{1}) & \hat {a}^{+}(\mathbf p_{2}) \end{vmatrix}?
$$

Comment: The Slater determinant is hidden in $|n_{p1}=1,n_{p2}=1\rangle$ and you do not need antisymmetrize once again. These are occupation number representation of Slater determinants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{vmatrix} \chi_{\mathbf{p}_1}(\mathbf{x}_1) & \chi_{\mathbf{p}_2}(\mathbf{x}_1) \\ \chi_{\mathbf{p}_1}(\mathbf{x}_2) & \chi_{\mathbf{p}_2}(\mathbf{x}_2) \end{vmatrix}
$$

corresponds to $a_{\mathbf{p}_1 s_1}^{\dagger} a_{\mathbf{p}_2 s_2}^{\dagger} |0\rangle$. Here $s$ is the spin for the fermions. In the Slater determinant $\mathbf{x}$ includes both spatial and spin parts.

Comment: it would be better to provide a reason for downvoting :(

Comment: Op asked 2×2 case, so there is no need to over generalize the situation ;)

Comment: P.S. I am not the person who downvotes your answer...

Comment: Thank you. Does it (2-fermionic state) formally correspond to
$$
\begin{vmatrix} \hat {a}^{+}(\mathbf p_{1}) & \hat {a}^{+}(\mathbf p_{2}) \\ \hat {a}^{+}(\mathbf p_{1}) & \hat {a}^{+}(\mathbf p_{2}) \end{vmatrix},
$$
or it is only coincidence?

Comment: Formally no, you need to specify the spins of the creation operators (unless the notations $\mathbf{p}_1$ and $\mathbf{p}_2$ include spins already) and acts them on the vacuum. The Slater determinant corresponds to $a^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{p}_1 s_1} a^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{p}_2 s_2} |0 \rangle$, where $|0\rangle$ is the vacuum.